# Looking for sample anomaly detection in bank transactions records (in TSQL or R)

Tags: sql-server, r

I want to detect unexpected transactions in bank transaction record and in GL entries.
Like for a supplier the amount are generally 2000$ or 5000$ per month, but suddenly there is a transaction with 10 000$ or 200$ which is unexpected.
I'll have multiple columns participating in this anomaly detection: customer, supplier, account number, transaction description, user entering the transaction (for the GL side) etc...

My data are in SQL Server, so I'm looking for sample code working in TSQL. Else I can rely on R scripts.

thanks for your help.

Comment: We need a schema (and preferably test data)

Comment: It sounds like you are asking us to write your business rules, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  If this is a programming question, can you please clarify what programming technique is it that you don't know how to do?

Comment: This should be a good start for you in Machine Learning:
https://gallery.azure.ai/Experiment/Online-Fraud-Detection-Step-1-of-5-Generate-tagged-data-2

Answer (score 0):

Might not be exactly what you're looking for, but with [Azure Machine Learning Studio](https://studio.azureml.net/) you can use One-Class classifier to create an experiment that detects anomalies depending on the threshold. And you can easy feed it the data from your SQL Server.

It might be an overkill, but you can use the free version, which is more than you need.

Answer (score 0):

An option would to use a SQL Windowing function to get the standard deviation of the transaction amount and look for entries that are more than 1 standard deviation away.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(
    Customer nvarchar(255),
    Supplier nvarchar(255),
    AccountNumber nvarchar(255),
    STD decimal(20, 2),
    Amount decimal(20, 2))


  INSERT INTO #tmp (Customer, Supplier, AccountNumber, Amount, STD)
  SELECT Customer, Supplier, AccountNumber, Amount,
    ABS(STDEV(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer, Supplier, AccountNumber))
  FROM SourceTable

  SELECT *
  FROM #tmp 
  WHERE STD >= 1
```